# How to add a database to a java application whith different intances in different computers

Tags: java, sql

I wondered a lot throughout google but I cannot find an answer to my question. When I develop a java application like a management system with own database, that follows the same structure of the tables, like other instances of itself but with different data, how can I put empty tables into my application and let to the final user the task to fullfill the tables with its own data. For example if I write a Money management system with a designed table structure how can I create a local database instance on the customer's computer? (I know how drivers and queries work)

Thank you very much for the attention.

Comment: Is this a <sql> language related problem? Seems more like a dbms/software issue.

Comment: what kind of java-app are talking about : standard-desktop, web-app ?

Comment: standard desktop app.

Comment: if standard then it's pretty forward, just create the db  and let the user populate (nothing more) ... do not see any issue

Comment: on standard desk-app each running instance (on different computers) will operate on their computers( local_db ) ...

Comment: Provide details as edits to your Question rather than as Comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Database migration tools

You asked:

> how can I put empty tables into my application

You need to run SQL scripts defining your tables and columns, and for defining other database objects such as indexes and triggers. You need to track what old scripts have already been run and what new scripts need to be run. You could do this tracking yourself, but nowadays we have tools to assist.

Use a [database migration tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_migration) such as [*Flyway*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyway_(software)) or [*Liquibase*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquibase) to track every one of your SQL scripts. At runtime, the migration tool checks the current database condition to see if any of the SQL scripts have not yet been run, and then runs the needed ones.

Search Stack Overflow to learn more. This topic has been addressed many times already.